# Preciso de ajuda para resolver esse exercício (ex: 8 project euler)!

Tags: c, arquivo

A questão pede que em um numero de 1000 dígitos encontremos o maior produto de 30 números adjacentes ([link da questão](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8)), Sei que posso fazer isso apenas jogando numa string de 1000 digitos e sair verificando se de 1 a 5 é menor que 2 a 6, e assim por diante... mas estou aprendendo manipulação de arquivos e gostaria de fazer o exercício utilizando esse método, portanto cheguei a esse código sem êxito o resultado está incorreto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define len 4

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
    char nums[len];
    int tot = 1, maior = 0,  cont, reset=1;

    FILE *numero; //cria um poiteiro numero do tipo arquivo
    if((numero = fopen("texto.txt", "r")) == NULL){ //caso ocorra algum erro na hora de abrir o arquivo informe erro e saia do programa
        printf("Error!\n");//mostra erro
        system("wait");//aguarda o usuario pressionar enter
        exit;//sair
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){//percorre cada caractere do numerozao
        if ( cont == len){
            cont = 0;
        }
        fscanf(numero, "%c", &nums[cont]);//coloca o valor do caractere em nums
        tot = 1;//reset o valor de tot
        for ( int a = 0; a < len; a++){
            tot *= (nums[a]-'0');//soma todos os valores de nums
        }
        if( tot > maior){
            maior = tot;//caso o valor novo seja maior que o valor antigo, atualize esse valor
        }
        if ( cont == -1*(1-len)){
            i = reset;//reseta o valor de i para que seja pego todos os valores
            reset++;
        }
        cont++;
    }
    printf("%d\n", maior);
    fclose(numero);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS );
}
```

Arquivo txt: 7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450

Comment: Como você sempre irá considerar grupos de 5 então leia 5 algarismos, calcule o produto, desloque os algarismos uma posição para a direita e leia outro algarismo na última posição e refaça o cálculo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O programa abaixo acha o maior produto, mas creio que a questão pede o trigésimo maior e não o maior de todos. Para isso creio que a maneira mais fácil seria guardar em um array os 996 produtos, ordená-los e pegar o trigésimo.

```
#include <stdio.h>    
int main() {
    char nums[5], aux[5];
    int cont=0, i, a, maior, prod;

    FILE *numero;
    numero = fopen("texto.txt", "r");

    for (i=0; i < 1000; i++) {
        fscanf(numero, "%c", &nums[cont]);
        if (cont < 4)
            cont++;
        else {
            prod = 1;
            for (a=0; a < 5; a++)
                prod *= (nums[a] - '0');
            if (i == 4)
                maior = prod;
            else {
                if (prod > maior)
                    maior = prod;
            }
            for (a=1; a<5; a++)
                nums[a-1] = nums[a];
        }
    }
    printf("Maior: %d\n", maior);
    fclose(numero);
    return 0;
}
```

Para 30 algarismos consecutivos:

```
#include <stdio.h>    
int main() {
    char nums[30];
    int cont=0, i, a, maior, prod;

    FILE *numero;
    numero = fopen("texto.txt", "r");

    for (i=0; i < 1000; i++) {
        fscanf(numero, "%c", &nums[cont]);
        if (cont < 30)
            cont++;
        else {
            prod = 1;
            for (a=0; a < 30; a++)
                prod *= (nums[a] - '0');
            if (i == 30)
                maior = prod;
            else {
                if (prod > maior)
                    maior = prod;
            }
            for (a=1; a<30; a++)
                nums[a-1] = nums[a];
        }
    }
    printf("Maior: %d\n", maior);
    fclose(numero);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Segmentation fault (core dumped).... Não funcionou!

Comment: Logo após o fopen teste se a abertura do arquivo ocorreu com sucesso:  if (numero == NULL) {
  printf("Erro na abertira do arquivo\n");
  exit(1):
 }

Comment: Esse erro foi resolvido, contudo o resultado está incorreto no project euler

Comment: Como eu comentei eu não entendi este aspecto do trigésimo valor. É o trigésimo em ordem crescente ou decrescente? Você já havia feito o exercício sem o uso de arquivo? Sabe qual é a resposta?

Comment: O exercício pede para que encontremos os 30 numeros adjacentes (lado a lado) cujo produto seja o maior... ainda não o fiz, estou sem tempo... assim q terminá-lo mando aqui para complementar a resposta

Comment: Bom, não é o que diz a questão no link que você postou: "The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832."

Comment: mas este é o exemplo que eles nos dão, a pergunta mesmo está mais abaixo:

"Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product. What is the value of this product?"